# How to sort a PySpark dataframe rows by the order of a list?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pySpark dataframe with multiple columns and a list with the items with one of the column items. I want to sort rows by the order of the given list.

| col_A | col_B | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 | b3 |

col_A_itm_order = ['a2', 'a3', 'a1']

Expected output

| col_A | col_B | col_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
| a3 | b3 | c3 |
| a1 | b1 | b1 |

I found a similar question for Pandas dataframe, but not for PySpark.

Comment: What of values not in list

Comment: @thebluephantom The list contains all the values of the column :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession as ss
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Assuming spark is already created
spark = ss.builder.appName("Sortdf").getOrCreate()

# DataFrame
data = [("a1", "b1", "c1"),
        ("a2", "b2", "c2"),
        ("a3", "b3", "c3")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col_A", "col_B", "col_C"])

def sortdf(cl, order):
    
    # Create the sort_logic dynamically
    sort_logic = [col(cl).desc() if x.startswith('-') else col(cl).asc() for x in order]
    
    # Apply sorting to the DataFrame
    res = df.orderBy(*sort_logic)

    return res

# Example
r = sortdf("col_A", ["a2", "a3", "a1"])
r.show()
```